# NDatabase crashes on Order By

Tags: c#, ndatabase

I'm using NDatabase to do some really simple object storage - basically building a persistent work queue. The plan is to create a set of objects, persist them to disk, then read them back sorted on one of the properties. I cannot get the "sorted" part working - NDatabase throws an Exception.

Here's the supertype of the objects I want to persist:

```
public abstract class Instruction: IComparable, IComparable<Instruction>
{
    public virtual DateTime Timestamp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Instruction other)
    {
        if (this.Timestamp.Equals(other.Timestamp))
            return 0;

        return (this.Timestamp < other.Timestamp) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Instruction;
        return other == null ? -1 : this.CompareTo(other);
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm creating the object store:

```
using (var odb = OdbFactory.Open(storeName))
{
    odb.IndexManagerFor<Instruction>().AddIndexOn("TimestampIndex", "Timestamp");
    foreach (var instruction in instructions)
    {
        odb.Store(instruction);
    }
    odb.IndexManagerFor<Instruction>().RebuildIndex("TimestampIndex");
}
```

And here's how the store is being retrieved later on:

```
lock (this.odb)
{
    var q = odb.Query<T>();
    q.Descend("Timestamp").OrderAscending();
    var objectSet = q.Execute<T>(true, 0, maxCount);
    instructions = objectSet.ToList();

    foreach (var instruction in instructions)
    {
        odb.Delete(instruction);
    }

    odb.IndexManagerFor<Instruction>().RebuildIndex("TimestampIndex");

    odb.Commit();
}
```

This throws an `NDatabase.Exceptions.OdbRuntimeException` on the `ToList()` call. Digging in to the exception properties gives the message

> "NDatabase has thrown an Exception Error:222:Operation not supported :
>   CopyTo"

However, if I comment out the line `q.Descend("Timestamp").OrderAscending();` then it works fine - though it's obviously not ordered.

Can anyone help shed any light on this, please?

Comment: What exception ndatabase is throwing?

Comment: @SivaGopal I've edited the question with the exception's error message.

Comment: sorry but odb.Query<T>(); will return an IList<T> which doesn't have a Descend(string s) method or I've missed something? What version is this?

Comment: @InvernoMuto I'm on version 3.8.0. In this version at least, `IOdb.Query<>()` returns an `IQuery` object.

Comment: @leppie I'm not sure why you think that. If you mean the first Descend() call, that's not about sorting - that call adds another node to the query graph. The IQuery object that it returns has calls for both OrderAscending() and OrderDescending();

Comment: @TarkaDaal: Ignore my comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is telling you that NDatabase's base implementation of `ICollection<T>` (`AbstractBTreeCollection<T>`) does not support the method `CopyTo()`, which is called by the LINQ extension method `ToList()` that you are using.

So the question then becomes, why does this only happen when you do intermediary work using OrderByAscending, but not on the result of Query directly?

Looking at the source code for NDatabase, I can see why:
http://ndatabase.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

```
if (_inMemory)
{
    if (_query != null && _query.HasOrderBy())
        _result = new InMemoryBTreeCollection<T>(_query.GetOrderByType());
    else
        _result = new SimpleList<T>();
}
else
{
    // result = new InMemoryBTreeCollection((int) nbObjects);
    if (_query != null && _query.HasOrderBy())
        _result = new LazyBTreeCollection<T>(_storageEngine, _returnObjects);
    else
        _result = new LazySimpleListFromOid<T>(_storageEngine, _returnObjects);
}
```

In `QueryResultAction<T>.Start()`:

- If you have an order by, you get an instance of an implementation of 
  `AbstractBTreeCollection`, which doesn't support `CopyTo`.
- If you don't have an order by, you get an instance of `SimpleList` or `LazySimpleListFromOid`, which do support `CopyTo`.

Looking into the examples for NDatabase, they are not expecting you to call `ToList()`:
https://ndatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=5-minutes-tutorial

This is a fairly painful implementation nuance. You may want to raise it as an issue with them.